# Will Disk File Have Better Performance When Opened Exclusively?

Tags: windows, file, share, mode

I notice that in many disk storage systems, such as SQLite, IStream(Created on File). When they are opened exclusively, they will get better performance.

For SQLite, it is at "PRAGMA LOCKING_MODE" section in https://blog.devart.com/increasing-sqlite-performance.html

For IStream, based on document for SHCreateStreamOnFileEx at https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/windows/win32/stg/stgm-constants, it said "In transacted mode, sharing of STGM_SHARE_DENY_WRITE or STGM_SHARE_EXCLUSIVE can significantly improve performance because they do not require snapshots."

Therefore, I just wonder in Windows, whether the genereal disk file will get better performance if I open it as read mode, together with share exclusively mode? In the past, when opening a file for read purpose, I only set it share mode to deny write instead of share exclusively, though there are no other processes or threads that will try to read the file at the same time.

Comment: I would expect some programs, (e.g. databases), to not have any [FILE_SHARE_*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilea) bits set when opening the file - strictly to prevent another process instance from corrupting it.  Office Documents also do this.  But I've never heard of this technique being used to increase I/O throughput or performance.  But if it does, I'd love to hear about it.

Comment: @selbie, I have just updated the post to include the information about exclusively open SQlite or IStream to increase performance.